# Fixed transparent header in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to add a Fixed transparent header in a `UITableView` similar to the one on the attached image (LHR-SYD / 372 Results). Is this a "built in" component in xcode/ios or how is it done ?

[image: an image of an ios app that has a fixed transparent header on top of a uitableview]

Answer (score 7):

use these methods ,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

above method for setting the view.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

above method for setting the title .
see this one ,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UILabel *lbl = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    lbl.text=@"LHR-SYD / 372 Results";
    return lbl;
}
```

by using above method you can add different objects to your headerview.

(OR)

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return @"LHR-SYD / 372 Results";
}
```

this one your Requirement i think so.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 30;
}
```

you can set height of the header view using this code

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default header view bg:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    header.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [header.backgroundView.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

  UIView *transparentView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,10)];
  transparentView.backGroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
  return transparentView;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is actually the default header for a `UITableView`. All you have to do is implement the `titleForHeaderInSection` method and it will appear. Check out the documentation for that method, it helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is built in. The attached screenshot is of a `UITableView` that uses sections.

You can also customise the view of a section's header. Refer to `[tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:]`(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview). However, what you see is the default view so you only have to implement sections and `titleForHeaderInSection`.